# Rails Model Validation for Devise: Update user login automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Users for my application will be switching email domains soon (company name change), and I'd like them to be able to keep their data. However, my app is using LDAP, so it's not just a setting I can have them update in their account page. I want it to check their employee number and automatically change their login/email (unique identifier for the db) if that employee number belongs to a current user. Here's what I have so far:

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :ldap_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable
  validate :check_migrate

  def check_migrate
    if id.nil? # User is new
      uid_number = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.login, 'uidNumber').first
      old_user = User.where(uid_number: uid_number).first
      if old_user
        old_user.update!(login: self.login) # Gets rolled back after this method
        errors.add(:login, "User login migrated to new email! Please sign in again")
      else
        self.uid_number = uid_number
      end
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
end
```

This currently is displaying the following error message on completion:
[image: Rails Validation Failed Error]
.

But I want it to return to the login page with a nice flash message from the error I added. Also, it's not persisting the old_user.update! change. It appears to work inside the method, but after the error, it's back to the old value.

Is there a good way to do this?
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your own session controller that inherits from Devise's, and modify the create method to your liking:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    # change to whatever
  end
end
```

You also should modify your routes to make sure your server picks this up. This is the relevant section in my routes (you can see I modified things a lot):

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions', :confirmations => 'confirmations', :passwords => 'passwords'}
```

Good luck